# Ionic 2/3 Back Button appears next to menu

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In my app I have at every page the "hideBackButton" on true. This works except on one page where that button appears next to the menu button (see screenshot). This back button hasn't any functionality here.
Is there a way to hide it? Perhaps by a css hack? Any help would be great. 
There are pages where the back button should be visible, so I can't hide it in the entire app.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

One way to hide the back button would be to set that page as the root page, instead of just pushing it. So instead of

`this.navCtrl.push(ThePage)`

try with

`this.navCtrl.setRoot(ThePage)`

That's one way to do it. If you don't want to change that, you can replace the `ion-navbar` for an `ion-toolbar`. So instead of

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
            Events Feed
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

You can hide the back button with this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
            Events Feed
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

I'd prefer the first fix, but I'm not sure of what are the requirements on your end.

Comment: I am already working with the setRoot. Strange is that I don't have it on my device but client has it on his device. I try the solution with the toolbar also.